# Securing a contact form script

Tags: php, email, contact-form, secure-coding

**Hello!** I am just wondering how secure is this contactform script I just made? My teacher was nagging at me a long time ago when I made my contactforms.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){

    $myemail  =    "email@adress.com";
    $name      =    $_POST['name'];
    $email    =    $_POST['email'];
    $phone    =    $_POST['phone'];
    $subject  =    $_POST['subject'];
    $comments =    $_POST['comments'];

   if($name == 0 || !preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email) || !preg_match("/^\d{2}(-\d{3}){2}(\d{2})?$/", $phone) || $subject == 0 || $comments == 0){

       $error_message = 'Something was written wrong..';

   } else {

       $message = "Hello!
       Your contact form has been submitted by:
       Name: $name
       E-mail: $email
       Phone: $phone
       Comments: $comments
       End of message";
       mail($myemail, $subject, $message);
       $error_message = 'Your message was sent!';

    }
}
```

Any suggestions of how to make it secure?

P.S. [Securing a Contact Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685761/securing-a-contact-form) and [Securing a php contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050718/securing-a-php-contact-form) are both for WordPress and that's not what I am out for.

Comment: You might want to post this over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Seems like its vulnerable to mail injection, this means sending (spam-) mails via your server by injecting custom headers and a custom body. Can be fixed by stripping \r and \n off the subject and everything else you put unfiltered into your mail's headers.

Comment: Perhaps the teacher was referring to human/bot checkers such as [recaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha).

Comment: @DanielM Something like this? `$subject = "$_POST['subject']\r\n";`

Comment: @Nworks: No, the exact contrary: `$subject = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), array('', ''), $subject);` You should so some research on this topic to understand this.

Comment: I don't see where the `$_POST['subject']` should be :/

Comment: @DanielM second array() is not necessary, just '' suffices.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com: I'm pretty sure old php versions don't accept that syntax but yes, the current ones do.

Comment: @DanielM: maybe, but anyone using anything older than 5.x is simply asking for troubles anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a function to validate the entries such as :

```
function check_input($data)
 {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
 }
```

And

```
        $name      =    check_input($_POST['name']);
        $email    =    check_input($_POST['email']);
        $phone    =    check_input($_POST['phone']);
        $subject  =    check_input($_POST['subject']);
        $comments =    check_input($_POST['comments']);
```

And

```
     if ($name && $email && $phone && $subject && $comments) {
         Send contact form...

}
```

and of course you can add captcha to make it more secure.

Comment: That's terrible advice. Read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: @deceze well it is 5 years old...post an updated answer.

Comment: @Michael It was terrible advice 5 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing insecure in your code really beside lack of data validation. You just collect form data and send it out. so the only 'insecurity' is that you would be easily spammed through that form unless any sort of captcha is used. I am not sure at the moment, but it may be possible to trick mail() to add more receipients with crafted $subject, so it would be save to ensure it's oneliner and strip any CRLFs

Comment: So I have to use a CAPTCHA? What do you mean by strip any CRLFs?

Comment: He meant what i meant. CRLF = Carriage return / Line feed (\r\n). Stripping them off means to remove them.

Comment: I would also strongly suggest staying away from mail() and forget about it ever existed. It's as dumb as can be (which is a good thing if you know you need that - which is almost never the case). There are lot of dedicated libraries for sending mails which can take care of many of these problems off of your head with  building the mail structure or handling attachements or dealing with authenticated smtp, that using mail() should never be even considered. Take a look at PHP Mailer - easy, nice and tested.