# Trouble completing a simple contactform

Tags: php, contact-form

I am a novice coder currently working on my very first php project. A website has a simple php contactform I'm trying to complete but I keep running into unexpected errors. I have tried many things now that I found on Stackoverflow and solved some errors myself, but I am at a loss right now. I hope someone would review my code to help me see what I'm missing here. Any help to get me back on track is much appreciated.

*edit: tried to make this post more on topic*

What I want this script to do: 

- make name, email and message required fields

- make form secure against malicious intent. That is why I added the check_input function, following [Securing a contact form script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079947/securing-a-contact-form-script)

Complete code as of now:

```
<?php

$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? check_input($_POST['name']) : ""; 
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? check_input($_POST['email']) : ""; 
$company = isset($_POST['company']) ? check_input($_POST['company']) : ""; 
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? check_input($_POST['message']) : ""; 
$from = 'From: ZZZ Reactieformulier';
$to = 'emailadres@mailserver.nl';
$subject = 'Reactie via website';


$body = "Afzender: $name\n E-mailadres: $email\n Bedrijfsnaam: $company\n 
Bericht: $message";

function check_input($data){
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}


if ($_POST['submit']) {
        if ($name !='' && $email !='' && $message !='') {
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
                echo '<p>Uw bericht is succesvol verzonden!</p>';
            } else {
                echo '<p>Er is iets misgegaan, probeer het alstublieft 
                         opnieuw</p>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '</p>De velden Naam, E-mail en Bericht zijn verplicht</p>';
        }

    }   
?>
```

Comment: The ternary operator is `?:`, not merely `?`. That's the syntax issue.

Comment: That "`check_input`" function doesn't "check" anything; a better name would be "`mangle_input`". Read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: @deceze I added that function based on something I read here [Secure contact form script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079947/securing-a-contact-form-script)

Comment: That's a terrible answer FWIW.

Comment: Yup, W3S is also terrible.

Comment: @deceze I found the same modus operandi on W3schools
[See here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp) 
I read the file you proposed. Interesting stuff, however perhaps due to my limited coding experience, I'm not sure how to implement the given principles in my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ternary operator are wrong :

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? check_input($_POST['name']);
```

should be

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? check_input($_POST['name']) : "";
```